# Postgresql user "postgres" requires password in order to create db

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos7

I am running centOS 7 and trying to create a postgresql database

I entered to following to install and initiate database

```
yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch.rpm

sudo yum install postgresql11

sudo yum install postgresql11-server

sudo /usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-setup initdb

sudo systemctl enable postgresql-11

sudo systemctl start postgresql-11
```

so after this i try to create a database by entering

```
sudo createdb mydb
```

receive:

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

so now i realize i need to be on the postgre user

and cannot create a db with this command:

```
sudo -u postgres createdb mydb
```

Recieve:

```
could not change directory to "/home/<user>": Permission denied
```

I am able to get the postgre prompt by entering the following

```
sudo -u postgres -i
psql
```

but when i enter `sudo -u postgres -1` i get a new bash prompt `-bash-4.2$`

when i try to create a database in this prompt with `sudo createdb mydb` it asks for a password for postgres and can't go on from there,
what is this password? i read that by default it shouldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try 
`sudo -i -u postgres` 
`psql` `CREATE DATABASE yourbase;` 
`\c yourbase` ?

Comment: Whoops, i dont know why i didnt try to create it from the prompt. that works, thanks